# Why can I use a pointer as the buffer for write() but need to use the pointers address as the buffer for read()?

Tags: c, pointers, pipe

I'm trying to pipe a single character from a parent process to a child process. Usually this is done with a simple variable but I'm trying it out with a pointer. If it's done with a simple variable (`var`) the buffer argument for both write() and read() is `&var`, but when I use a pointer (`*ptr`), the argument for read() is `ptr` and the argument for write() is `&ptr`.

I'm new to C and I can't quite wrap my head around why this is the case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

  char *chPtr;
  int fd[2];
  pid_t pid;

  char value = 'z';

  pipe(fd);
  pid = fork();

  if (pid) {     // Parent
    close(fd[0]);
    chPtr = &value;
    write(fd[1], chPtr, 1);
    close(fd[1]);
  }

  if (! pid) {   // Child
    close(fd[1]);
    read(fd[0], &chPtr, 1);
    printf("the result is %c\n", (int)chPtr);
    close(fd[0]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you find that it should be `&chPtr`? Unless I'm missing something, it should in fact be just plain `chPtr`. `read` ( http://linux.die.net/man/2/read ) takes a `void*` as the second parameter so you just pass `chPtr` since it's already a `char*`. Taking the address by writing `&chPtr` would make it a `char**` which is not what `read` takes.

Comment: Also that `printf` looks doubly suspicious. The "%c" specifier expects a `char`, but you're passing an `int`. Not only that, but the way that `int` is created is by casting a `char*`. Very rarely will you ever need to cast a pointer type to an actual scalar. Likely what you want is `*chPtr` without the `(int)` cast.

Answer (score 1):

Your child implementation is not doing what you expect. Although it works, it is really a design bug.

The read() function reads into a buffer allocated by the caller. Because you are passing &chPtr to read(), you are using the memory for the pointer as your buffer, which happens to work since you are only reading a single character, which fits into the memory for a pointer.

Normally you would want something like:

```
if (! pid) {   // Child
    char buf[1];
    close(fd[1]);
    read(fd[0], buf, 1);
    printf("the result is %c\n", buf[0]);
    close(fd[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A pointer does what its name suggests, it points to a memory location. If the case of the `read`, you are storing a value in the pointer instead of placing the value in the location to which it points. In fact, by using the `&` operator on a pointer you are in fact creating a pointer to a pointer. That's why the explicit cast is required to use the value in a `printf`.

Instead, you should set the pointer to the address of `value` and then use the pointer normally like so:

```
chPtr = &value;
read(fd[0], chPtr, 1);
printf("the result is %c\n", value);
```

It is more common to use an array of bytes (i.e. char[]) instead of a pointer, or instead allocate memory on the heap (see malloc).